# GCP Cloud SQL as Replica from AWS RDS Mysql

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, cloud-sql-proxy

We are planning to migrate huge tera bytes of data from AWS RDS My-SQL store to GCP Cloud SQL.

We are planning to setup a replica in cloud sql to begin with. What could be possible migration strategy and approach?

GCP Cloud SQL doesn't allow external cloud replication? It blocks replicating data from master in aws rds and replica in cloud sql. GCP blocks "change master command" in cloud sql replica. Has anyone faced similar issue? or constraint? If yes, what is the alternative to setup a replica in gcp cloud sql?

Comment: I guess that you are searching for [this](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/replication/replication-from-external) documentation. Bear in mind to fulfil server [requirements](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/replication/replication-from-external#server-requirements).

Comment: @TasosV we have gone through this documentation. But issue is at GCP Cloud SQL, it is not allowing to setup a Cloud SQL Mysql as a Slave. To enable slave in cloud sql mysql, "change master command"  has to be executed. This is not working.

Comment: @Prakhyat Can you point to the exact step on the [document referenced by Tasos](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/replication/replication-from-external) where you are blocked and why. It is quite explicit on the steps to follow and it doesn't seem to mention the need to use "change master command". Consider also editing your question to clarify these points.

Answer (score 1):

You can now use Google Cloud Platform's [Database Migration Service](https://cloud.google.com/database-migration) to bootstrap a Cloud SQL database with data from your RDS instance and automatically begin replication afterwards. You can leave the migration in "replicating" status or delete the migration job after the replica is replicating new changes.

The external primary database (source) will appear as the source for the GCP SQL Replica

[image]

At a this time or before deleting the migration job, you could promote the replica to make it the primary database.